# Search option for own questions?

Tags: support, questions, search

Is there a search option for your own questions?

It would be nice if there is, because after a while, you remember asking a question way back, but you forgot the solution, so you want to search through your questions for that specific question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A4993010+%09is%3Aquestion

Comment: @Rizier123 It brings me to a page with "user:4993010  is:question" in the search box.

Comment: It shows your questions ;)

Comment: Just to clarify, I believe you are saying you would like to search and sort your questions by topic. So if you remembered vaguely that you had asked a question on WPF grid binding, you'd like to do a search

 "user:me is:question topic:WPF, grid, binding".

Have I got that right?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Without having to remember your user ID, you can always use the shorthand `user:me` in the search box.

So, for your questions, you'd type:

```
user:me is:question
```

Comment: And there are the shortcuts: `is:q` and `is:a`

Comment: And then you type your string that you want to search for after 'question' with a space. Also, the is:q is for questions you've asked, and is:a is for answers you've given, for future users who visits this page.

Comment: Might be handy to mention that in order for the `user:me` to function the user in question needs to be logged into the site.

Comment: I'm lazy and instead of typing `user:me` I click my username top-left, which reloads the page with e.g. `user:12345` prefilled in the search box.

Answer (score 4):

I use google, and include my name in the search, setting the site to stackoverflow.com